# Xlsx styles getting wrong fill pattern

Tags: xml, excel, openxml

I am writing an xlsx file where I want to apply my own styles to cells in a worksheet.  I have a case where style 1 and style 2 both specify solid red, but when I open it in excel the first is gray stippled but the second is what I expect.  I am stumped..  Here are some bits of xml from the attached file.

In the worksheet, I have 2 cells:

```
  <x:c t="inlineStr" s="2">
    <x:is>
      <x:t>looks right</x:t>
    </x:is>
  </x:c>
  <x:c t="inlineStr" s="1">
    <x:is>
      <x:t>looks wrong</x:t>
    </x:is>
  </x:c>
```

In the styles.xml file, I define these cell styles as follows:

```
<x:cellXfs>
  <x:xf borderId="0" fillId="0" fontId="0" numFmtId="0"/>
  <x:xf fillId="1" applyFill="1"/>
  <x:xf fillId="2" applyFill="1"/>      
</x:cellXfs>
```

Where the fills are:

```
<x:fills>
  <x:fill>
    <x:patternFill patternType="none"/>
  </x:fill>
  <x:fill>
    <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
      <x:fgColor rgb="FFFF0000"/>
    </x:patternFill>
  </x:fill>
  <x:fill>
    <x:patternFill patternType="solid">
      <x:fgColor rgb="FFFF0000"/>
    </x:patternFill>
  </x:fill>
</x:fills>
```

Fills 1 and 2 are both solid red, so cell styles 1 and 2 should be identical, right?  But they are not.

Is this an Excel bug?  Is there a pre-defined fill style numbered 1 that overrides my definition?

Hmm, I don't see how to attach a file to a question...

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that my second guess was right.  Fill #1 is hardwired to gray125.  Excel ignores the definition of this fill while reading the xml.  Would have been nice if this were documented somewhere.

Comment: After pulling my hair out for an hour about why the fill I created for my custom headers was being ignored even though everything was set right I found this. I added a dummy fill at #1 and made my custom one #2 and it worked perfectly.

Comment: indeed its stated to be zero based index but it only work from 1 and up